# Spark (Java API) - add new fields to JSON column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark to read rows from Cassandra, one of the columns is a JSON object. Here is the schema and sample row in the Dataset:

```
root
 |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+
|attributes                                                                      |id      |col1     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+
|[[usage,2,5.0,12], [price,1,10.0,48], [hair,1,10.0,23737], [curls,1,10.0,30807]]|19400335|val_str_1|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+
```

Loading from the table is done with the following schema:

```
ArrayType schema =
                DataTypes.createArrayType(
                        new StructType(
                                new StructField[] {
                                        new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                                        new StructField("count", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                                        new StructField("score", DataTypes.DoubleType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                                        new StructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty())}));
```

Is it possible to inject new fields to the `attributes` column - put the value from `id` column under the root and put the value from `col1` column inside the struct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `transform` function to update each struct element in the array :

```java
df.withColumn("attributes", expr("transform(attributes, x -> struct(x.name as name, x.count as count, x.score as score, x.id as id, id as root_id, col1 as root_col1))"))
```

For **spark <2.4**, you can explode the array column, update then groupby to collect list again :

```
df.withColumn("attr_structs", explode(col("attributes")))
    .withColumn("attr_structs", struct(col("attr_structs.*"), col("id").alias("root_id"), col("col1").alias("root_col1")))
    .groupBy("id", "col1")
    .agg(collect_list(col("attr_structs")).alias("attributes"))
```

Comment: Should it work with Java as well? Getting error:

21/03/02 10:09:10 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
extraneous input '>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM',...
== SQL ==
transform(attributes, x -> struct(x.name as name, x.count as count, x.score as score, x.id as id, id as root_id))

Comment: @Seffyn it should.  What is you spark version?

Comment: spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0

Comment: @Seffy Ah `transform` function is only available from Spark 2.4+. try with the edited answer?

Comment: now it's complaining on this:

21/03/02 11:00:44 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(attributes)`;

Comment: @Seffy that is strange as the array is being exploded in the first step. Can you try with renaming as in the edited answer?